# Where did the ubuntu wily sources go?

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

I'm getting fail to fetch errors in apt-get:

> Failed to fetch
>   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]

I thought it was a sources error, or DNS error, but /dists/wily/ really doesn't exist at us.archive.ubuntu.com anymore. Nor does it exist in several mirrors I tried. Where did it go? What's the valid wily source now?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `wily` version is in `EOL` (End of Life): no longer supported.

You must follow these steps to use apt-get, by setting the use of oldversion repositories:

[https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades][1]

1. modify with `sudo` the file `/etc/apt/sources.list`, e.g.:

   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
2. put into it:

   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main universe restricted multiverse
   deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main universe restricted multiverse

   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main universe restricted multiverse
   deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main universe restricted multiverse

   deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main universe restricted multiverse
   deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main universe restricted multiverse
3. save the file
4. do: `sudo apt-get update`
   [1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades